# How can I customize the behavior of the green 'expand window' button so that it only maximizes (instead of taking over the entire screen)?

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite

I just upgraded my macbook pro to Yosemite and this new behavior of the green window button is driving me nuts. I only want to expand a window to maximum size (and keep the menu bar showing). The new default behavior is to totally take over the screen, which is just too much, I find it disorienting. I want to go back to the way Mavericks did it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing `Alt+Shift+maximise`.

Also thanks to [pixelfairy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2840370/pixelfairy) for finding `[BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.de/)` to change the zoom button maximize behavior.

Comment: Thanks. Shift key doesn't seem to have any effect on the behavior. Right Zoom looks interesting but I'm not sure how I feel about installing an unsigned app from 2013.

Comment: @pixelfairy try doing alt+shift+maximise this is also one of the way i just found.

Comment: thanks!! alt+shift works! Do you know if there is a way to make alt+shift work to take over the screen and switch the default behavior to be maximize.

Comment: @pixelfairy Sorry, I don't have any idea of how to make zoom button behave as it does while alt+shift is pressed. But I will comment it out/edit my answer if I find one. Also if you get any, do comment it or self answer it. It may be helpful for others

Comment: I found this http://osxdaily.com/2015/03/11/change-the-green-button-maximize-behavior-in-os-x-yosemite-with-bettertouchtool/ if you want to edit your answer I'll happily award you the points. I really appreciate the help and knowing that I'm not the only person trying to figure this out.